# How to draw a 2D arrow in android drawing view using canvas( looks like Skitch app drawing arrow )

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

I'm not well experienced with the android canvas. I have searched many websites and I'm not successful enough to find even the samples for the 2D arrow. Any reference that matches with this 2D arrow would be very helpful to me. I need this arrow in my project drawing view when user chooses arrow to draw.

[image: drawing arrow in the skitch application]

Answer (score 1):

Android Canvas has a few draw methods like `drawLine()`, `drawRect()`, `drawCircle()` you would normally use a combination of these images to create what you want.  It also has a method `drawPath()` that draws images by feeding it x,y coords.  That could work for you but I don't suggest it (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html).  Working with the canvas is generally complex and for the overlay you want to do I would not suggest it.  If possible rather use a library like https://github.com/iammert/MaterialIntroView.